# Casting a string to a func type in GoLang

Tags: go

I have a string which is the name of a function in GoLang.
I want to treat them as function. How should I do this? I tried to achieve it through reflect.* but I didn't find a valid path for my purpose.

I get the name fo handlers in a JSON file, and I want to execute those handlers. Something like this:

```
{
  "students/show" : "ShowStudents",
  "students/add" : "AddStudents"
}
```

Then I want to execute `ShowStudents()`, but don't know how to treat it like a variable of type `func`

Comment: Just to be clear, Go does not support 'casting' in the way that other languages mean it (e.g. C++). The title implies something impossible. However, it *is* possible to achieve what you're seeking by other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task can be broken down into two steps:

1. Extract function names
2. Run those functions (assuming that they are defined somewhere)

For step 1, I would unmarshal the JSON into a map[string]string, something like this:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fname)
mp := make(map[string]string)
json.Unmarshal(b, &mp)
```

Coming to Step 2. In Go, it's not possible to convert `string` directly to a function call, but it is possible to enumerate the methods of an object using `reflect` package. This can be used as a workaround in this case. Instead of writing those functions directly, bind them to a dummy type, something like this:

```
type T int

func (t T) ShowStudents() {
    fmt.Println("Showing Students")
}

func (t T) AddStudents() {
    fmt.Println("Adding Students")
}

func main() {
    var t T
    reflect.ValueOf(t).MethodByName("ShowStudents").Call(nil)
}
```

[Run this example](https://play.golang.org/p/utpswJP-ET0)

Answer (score 2):

establish a mapping between the keys in the json file and the functions, then use that to call the functions as they appear in the json

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func AddStudents() {
    fmt.Println("woo")
}

func ShowStudents() {
    fmt.Println("lots of students")
}

func main() {
    js := `{
  "students/show" : "ShowStudents",
  "students/add" : "AddStudents"
}`

    lookup := make(map[string]string)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(js), &lookup)
    dispatch := make(map[string]func())
    dispatch["students/show"] = ShowStudents
    dispatch["students/add"] = AddStudents

    for v, _ := range lookup {
        print(v)
        dispatch[v]()
    }
}
```

Comment: So it is useless to put anything inside JSON file. Because I wanted to have one single point of change for my routes. With you solution, I need to change two places when I want to add a new endpoint & handler.

Comment: You could write out the lookup table as JSON from the Go program instead of consuming it

Comment: This sample contains hardcoded mapping. You can use reflection to map input to functions dynamically.